# NSLayoutConstraint get real value

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

How to get real value of `Greater Than on Equal` `NSLayoutConstraint`.

When you get `constant` parameter when constraint in runtime is clearly more than that it still return the lowest possible value

Comment: may be your are updating constraint by changing constant and it is not affecting are real updated value you have to add this line too [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the actual value, you'd just look at the `frame` of the view. Yes, when using auto layout, you shouldn't be manually changing the `frame`, but if you want to see where the view is, just examine the `frame` property.

Comment: Ha, that's true. Working.

Comment: how to get constant value in runtime?

Comment: The `constant` of the constraint? Add an `IBOutlet` for the constraint and you can reference that. Or iterate through the `UIView`'s `constraints` to find the right one.

Comment: @Rob constant of constraints giving 0.0 every time